# iPhone X - Newly registered Apple ID

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, apple-id

I am new to Apple ecosystem and have just obtained an iPhone X. I bought it new from store and during first boot I have created a new Apple ID as I never had one earlier. Now my new phone has been registered to my new Apple ID. At present I want to use my iCloud ID which I have made after that, so my doubt is that is there such thing that i have to keep my Apple ID live (one which I have used during first boot) as my new iPhone that has been registered into it, or can I change the Apple id anytime? I need to understand how Apple ID works and what is the Apple iPhone/product registration onto Apple ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you create an iCloud account it is also automatically an Apple ID as well. So, based on your question, you now actually have two Apple IDs at your disposal. However, this doesn't mean you need to use both, or that you only have to use one. Let me explain...

An Apple ID *can* be used to access Apple services such as the iOS App Store, macOS App Store (if you have a Mac), Apple Music, iCloud, iMessage, FaceTime, and so on. So, if you wanted, you *could* use your Apple ID to sign in to all of Apple's services (i.e. using a single Apple ID and password).

However, you don't have to do it that way. For example, you could use your iCloud account to sign into iCloud on your iPhone X and still use the first Apple ID you created to sign into the App Store on your iPhone X. And you could manage these happily (and simultaneously) on your device. Some people even use three IDs (e.g. a different one for Game Center).

So, based on what you're wanting to do, you can choose to sign out of anywhere you've already used the first Apple ID and then sign back in with the iCloud account you created.

However, there are a couple of scenarios you should be aware of in case they apply to your circumstances:

- If you've *purchased* any apps (free or paid) from the App Store using a particular Apple ID, then you're going to need to enter that Apple ID's password when updating those particular apps in future. One way to get around this would be to delete those apps and then sign out of the App Store. Then, sign back in using the other ID and download those apps again. One negative of this approach is that you'd have to pay for it again if they weren't free.
- In the unlikely event that your first Apple ID is attached to one particular country's services (e.g. the US iTunes Store), and the second ID is attached to to another one (e.g. the UK iTunes Store), then you may lose access to any purchases you made using the first ID (depending on the content, as this doesn't apply in all cases). Regardless, this is not something you need to worry about, as this would only be the situation if you deliberately created accounts in multiple jurisdictions for a particular purpose - it's not something that would have happened by accident (unless you purchased the iPhone X in one country and created an Apple ID, and then visited/moved to another country and created your iCloud account there). However, if you were in this situation, then you can still choose to switch between IDs if/when you needed to access/view the other content.

Finally, if you've only just purchased the iPhone X and don't have a lot of data already on it, you could choose to set it up from scratch again and just use the ID you want. If this is the case, post a comment below and I'll explain how to go about doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. It clears almost all my doubts using Apple ID's. I got this, i have already reset the phone and set it up NEW using the icloud ID and signed into all the services of Apple's. So now i don't need the previous first apple ID which i used into signing the apple iphone X during first boot? like i need to get sure of it that apple does not keep such footprint that the apple ID used for device registration for first time needs to be kept handy for any lost/or warranty such things?

Comment: Before you reset your iPhone X, did you sign out of anything you were already signed into? Also, how did you go about resetting your iPhone X? Also, did you happen to have Find My iPhone enabled?

Comment: I have simple used the system setting menu and reset it by erasing all the data. Also i think i have not logged out from services before resetting, and find-my-iphone setting is automatically turned off while resetting your iphone, that i have noticed as i have got the mails later that it has been shut down. So all in all, after logging to new Apple id, my phone appears on the apple id login webpage when i browsed it, and after i logged into the other apple id which i removed, it does not shows the phone.

Comment: Obviously I wasn't there, but based on what you've said you *should* be fine. If you're at all concerned, just keep a record of your old Apple ID and password somewhere for safekeeping. By the way, welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you find this site to be a valuable resource for you!